# Marking a class as `internal static` using ModuleBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, class, reflection, static

I am generating a dynamic assembly using Reflection.Emit and everything works fine but the generated class is marked as `internal sealed` due to the following code:

```
var typeBuilder = moduleBuilder.DefineType("MyNamespace.Program", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Sealed);
```

I don't see any of the `TypeAttributes` members that would hint at `static`. It does not seem to be just a compiler convenience as I can see manually written classes show up as `static` in reflector tools.

How could I mark my own type as static?

Comment: Static classes are a C# concept which doesn't exist at the IL level. In IL you will need to respresent it by the two defining properties of a static class: it can't be instantiated (i.e.it's abstract) and it can't be derived from (i.e. it's sealed).

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Thanks. I knew that but wasn't thinking about it when looking at the type builders. Most likely because I'm used to the BindingFlags as used in query-only reflection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it to work using:

```
var builderType = builderModule.DefineType("MyNamespace.Program", TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.NotPublic | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Abstract);
```

This gives `internal static` which is what I wanted.